# Can't select rows by same day

Tags: python, sqlite

There is a given table in SQLite:
table : Someday

```
(date,high,low,volume)
(202207280901, 22200, 19500, 434040)
(202207280901, 22200, 19500, 434040)
(202207280903, 23400, 22200, 125861)
...
(202301151519, 22000, 21750, 45180)
(202301151520, 21850, 21450, 30786)
(202301151530, 21850, 21450, 24732)
```

How to fetch all rows by same day using python? Rows should be collected by date format YYMMDD.

Here is a snippet of pseudo code of what I expected to do:

```
query = "SELECT date from table Sameday  "
cursor.execute(query)
for i in [1,2,3] :
rows = cursor.fetchsomething()
   for row in rows :
      print(row)
```

expected result :

```
when i=1 # "2022-07-28" only
row = [202207280901,202207280902,..., 202207281430]
when i=2 # "2022-07-29" only
row = [202207290901,202207290902,..., 202207291430]
when i=3 # "2022-07-30" only
row = [202207300901,202207300902,..., 202207301430]
```

Comment: It's not clear what your input and expected output is. Can you update your post to clearly share the two tables?

Comment: I just want to read all data in a table by every same day only when I fetch data. so  that I work something on 1st day data then work on 2nd day data ... then work on last day data

Comment: "*SELECT date,high from A397030 Group By substr(date,1,8)*" - your query tells a different story about what you're trying to do. Note that it doesn't make sense to use a `GROUP BY` clause in presence of no aggregate functions. This looks like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/): if you don't explain your full problem, we're most likely wasting our and your time.

Comment: What do you exactly  mean by "all rows by same day"? `substr(date,1,8)` looks like you want to group the rows in your table by the date ignoring the time component of the date.

Comment: Thanks, lemon. you may be right. Googling about my question doesn't tell me answer of my question.\ Read data in table , then make them into dataframe works fine.But it takes a lot of time :(

Comment: Yes  Hölderlin. I want to collect data by day but, ignore time component .

Comment: but day is not date. there are 7 days  week, this will repeat each week. And date is a identifier for each day over all.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fetch all rows from the table
2. Create a dictionary to store the rows by date
3. Iterate your SQL collection, extract the date field and create a key in the dic.
4. sort rows by given key

code:

```
import sqlite3

#Connect to the database

conn = sqlite3.connect("Someday.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Fetch all rows

query = "SELECT * FROM Someday"
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

#Create dictionary

dates = {}
for row in rows:
    date = row[0][:6] #Extract the key in YYMMDD format
    if date not in dates:
        dates[date] = []
    dates[date].append(row)

#Loop through the dictionary and print each row

for date in dates:
    print(dates[date])

#Close the connection

conn.close()
```

Comment: Wow.  Let me try this code and I will let you know. Thanks a lot Hölderlin :)